# workflow illustrator photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, workflow

I have searched for an answer to this and found tidbits here: [workflow for print publishing childrens book](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20320/workflow-for-print-publishing-childrens-book) but it didn't answer my question fully.

My question is how do you usually divide the work when creating an image in Illustrator that will be finalized in Photoshop?

- do you finish as much as possible in Illustrator and just add details in Photoshop? Or
- do you paste each vector from Illustrator to Photoshop so that you can add individual effects to those layers in Photoshop? And in doing so, "puzzling" together the final image in PS?

Input appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make most of the silhouettes in illustator, then export them in smart layers to photoshop and paint proper shading, overlay textures and post-process the image.

Illustrator is good when it comes to drawing vectors, but Photoshop is far more versatile and powerful in terms of overall image editing.

Comment: I think you said the keyword here "silhouettes" - I used to draw with outlines but just now realized I should be making just that - silhouettes. And I will export these as smart layers. Thanks!